# Return filtered index in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to return all the rows in a column where a certain condition has been met.

So for example, assume this is spreadsheet 'one':

```
 A             B
Jay            Yes
Tim            No
Tom             
Lane           Yes
Luisa
```

I would like to return the names in spreadsheet one that have the value 'yes' in column B of spreadsheet one, leaving this as my desired out

```
   A           
   Jay         
   Lane
```

I tried doing this:

```
=IF(One!B:B="Yes"One!A:A)
```

But this returns this

```
A  
Jay
FALSE
FALSE
Lane
FALSE
```

Comment: I never understand why people add Excel tags after they've specified Google Sheets. The two share many things, but not all formulas (e.g. `QUERY` as in the posted answer). If you want GS specifically, please only use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 3):

In GS you can use:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"Select A where B = 'Yes'")
```

Or:

```
=FILTER(A:A,B:B="Yes")
```

The 2nd option would also work in Microsoft365.

### Reference

- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [FILTER function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(FILTER(B!B:B,A:A=Yes cell)," ")
```

This should be easier.  If you're referencing from a different "tab" add the tabs name.

```
=TEXT(FILTER(TabB!B:B,TabB!A:A=Yes cell)," ")
```

This is case sensitive from what I understand so it's worth noting in case of errors.